# Insert something between row 1 and row 2 by tcbitemize options

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to insert something automatically between row 1 and row 2 of typeset by tcolorbox tcbitemize environment. Here "automatically" means put the method in tcolorbox options, not in the enviroment body(that is to say,not by \tcbitem), like this:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,raster}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[<...,the method to insert something between row 1 and row 2,...>]
        %The first row
        \tcbitem some text
        \tcbitem some text
        %the second row
        \tcbitem some text
        \tcbitem some text
        .
        .
        .
    \end{tcbitemize}   
\end{document}
```

Can you help me with this question? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What do you want to insert? Is it some text? Is it some options change? Do you want to insert it only between rows 1 and 2? Not between all rows? Could you make some sketch with the desired result?

Comment: I want to insert some text between two rows

Answer (score 2):

Use `\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2,enhanced,frame hidden]` in order to produce an ordinary 'text' on a 2 - column line in a `tcbitemize` environment, which is very restrictive about its inner content.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2]
  % The first row
  \tcbitem some text
  \tcbitem some text

  \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2,enhanced,frame hidden,colback=white]
    Foo text

  % the second row
  \tcbitem some text
  \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** With some 'automatic' behaviour for the specific row where the special text should appear:

Use `raster row 2/.style={...}` where `{...}` contains some usual `tcolorbox` options or define a style with `\tcbset{}` (see below)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  myhiddenbox/.style={raster multicolumn=2,enhanced,frame hidden,colback=white}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2,raster row 2/.style=myhiddenbox]
  % The first row with 'important' boxes
  \tcbitem some text
  \tcbitem some text
  % Second row with some other text
  \tcbitem Foo text
  % Third row with 'important' boxes
  \tcbitem some text
  \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Hupfer, your solution does work. But what I want is to inert "Foo text" from the options area of tcbitemize, that is to say, \begin{tcbitemize}[<...,the method to insert something between row 1 and row 2,...>],not in the steps of adding content to raster by \tcbitem. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @lyl: My name is Christian Hupfer, not just Hupfer. And you are changing the question

Comment: I'm so sorry for using a wrong form of address. And as you see, if the text that I want to insert between row 1 and row 2 can be typeset in the area of tcolorbox option, it will be convinient when adding contents to raster without having to remember that I need to add someting among \tcbitem, espcially when several rasters with same configuration are to be typeset. That's the reason why I ask this question. Thank you.